# Terminal open 2 tabs in current folder

Tags: pantheon-terminal, release-juno

when i Open in terminal in folder, for example music folder, terminal starts with 2 tabs named Music in Current path,i want to disable this, disable opening two tabs in current folder

Comment: Thesame issue described [here](https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues/356) and [here](https://github.com/elementary/terminal/issues/245). they are marked as 'In Progress', let's hope they will get to it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue for me until the  latest update I installed on 01/04/2020. I verified on three different computers. No issue until this update was installed and this was the only update installed.

The "remember-tabs" and "save-exited-tabs" settings make no difference. An extra tab always opens for me.

Comment: Welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. This does not provide an answer to the question. Answer fields are dedicated for [answers](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) only. If you have a question and existing ones doesn't help you then you may [create a new question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Have a nice day!